# xslt transformation, with a log report, of the orphaned transformations

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have as input the following XML:

```
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
  <DATA RECORDS="3">
    <RECORD ID="1">
      <INTERNALID>5550</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>1</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>ZERO</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="2">
      <INTERNALID>5556</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>2</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SIX</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5557</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>3</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SEVEN</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
   <RECORD ID="93">
      <INTERNALID>9999</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>9</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>NINE</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and passing the path to another XML file:

b.xml

```
<TABLE NAME="ALT.CS">
  <DATA RECORDS="5">
    <RECORD ID="15">
      <RECNO>5555</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>ECHO</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="16">
      <RECNO>5556</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>FOXTROT</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="17">
      <RECNO>5557</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>GOLF</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

as a parameter, we can use:

XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-path">path/to/b.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="RECORD" use="RECNO" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CODAL">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="key('lookup', ../INTERNALID, document($lookup-path))" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="$match">
            <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$match/TOBEEXTRACTED"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number value="../SOMEID" format="A" />
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

result

```
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
  <DATA RECORDS="3">
    <RECORD ID="1">
      <INTERNALID>5550</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>1</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>ZERO</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="2">
      <INTERNALID>5556</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>2</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SIX [FOXTROT B]</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5557</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>3</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SEVEN [GOLF C]</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="93">
      <INTERNALID>9999</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>9</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>NINE</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

In XSLT 2.0, we can use xsl:result-document to create a secondary output file and populate it using a template matching orphaned nodes, as suggested by @michael.hor257k, but was not able to make it work, so the log here would have to report that INTERNALID 9999 WAS ORPHANED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you really use an XSLT 2.0 processor then simply add a template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="report.txt" method="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//RECORD[not(key('lookup', INTERNALID, document($lookup-path)))]" mode="report"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to make sure the necessary text document is created and the not matched RECORD elements are processed, then add a template

```
<xsl:template match="RECORD" mode="report">
  <xsl:text>INTERNALID </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="INTERNALID"/>
  <xsl:text> was orphaned.
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

to have that line output for each processed RECORD element in that mode.

Comment: Insert the two templates into your stylesheet, as top-level children of the `xsl:stylesheet` element of course.

Comment: think i did it correctly, but got the following: xsl: result-document is disabled when extension functions are disabled. I gave the following command java net.cf.saxon.Transform - o:output.xml -s:input.xml -xsl:style.xsl

Comment: I have never seen that message from Saxon so you will need to explain in more detail which edition and version of Saxon you have tried when you get that message. It might be worth a new question with the [tag:saxon] tag if you continue to have problems.

Comment: There's a configuration switch in Saxon called ALLOW_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS, designed to be switched off in environments where you are running untrusted stylesheets. This will also disable xsl:result-document. This switch seems to be set off in the environment you are running in: from the information you have given, I can't tell why.